# Always loading certain child object in neo4j

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

```
class Node {
    Long id;
    String name;

    @Relationship(type="NodeToCategory")
    Address address;

    List<NodeB> nodeBList;



}

//node B CLass

class NodeB {
    Long id;
    String someOther;

    @Relationship(type="NodeToCategory")
    Address address;

    List<NodeC> nodeCList;



}

class Address {
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

When I run a query with depth 2 on the `Node` it returns `nodeBList` but it does not return addresses of NodeB. I want to make sure whenever there is an address object it will always return address no matter the depth . It should not return Addresses of `NodeB` as `Null` .

One way of doing is to load all the address before and then trying to load 
`Node` . I am trying to avoid that. Is there any way of doing it via any annotations or other features that I do not know of in neo4jOGM ?

Comment: I think the only way to get what you want, is to convert Address into a normal property, and then put an index on Address if you need to search on address.

Comment: I don't want to search it .. I want to get address every time when loading any class rather than cutting it off.

Comment: If you don't do any searches on address, than you can just save address as a String property instead. You can save it as a JSON string if you want to store it as complex data. You can even annotate getters/setters to convert from a string to an object and vice-versa so that you can still use the pojo in your objects. This will make address based searching harder later on though if you end up needing that though. Other than that, I don't know if there is anything else you can do.

Comment: thats not an option ..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved it by using `@Query` and `pattern` in your `cypher`. It will also return `NodeB` with `address` for those with one address and null address for those without `address`.

```
@Query("MATCH (na: Node) " +
  "WHERE na.name={0} " +
  "WITH na " +
  "MATCH p=(na)-[*0..2]->(n) " +
  "RETURN p")
public Node getNode(String name);
```

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoman If you want `Address` of `Node` and for each `NodeA` linked to `Node` to be returned, then this query solve that problem. Do you want also `NodeC` address to be returned too if exist ?

Comment: As I said I dont want to return all the level 2 I want only the address. And when we use this kind of query pagination does not work also